# Combining UEFI Ubuntu with MBR Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mbr

After searching the internet for quite a while without finding a satisfying solution, I decided to ask a question here myself.

I'm running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18 in a dual-boot system on my computer for quite a time already. Just recently I screwed up the Ubuntu system and instead of repairing it, I decided reinstalling would be quicker.

So, I created a bootable USB stick, tried to reinstall (including formatting) Ubuntu next to Windows and got the following error

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/
```

Googling this error suggested, I just have to provide a `/boot/efi/` mountpoint during installation. This already felt a bit strange, since I'm sure I didn't do this for the first installation back then. I tried this anyways and the system got installed successfully. The downside was, grub wasn't able to detect Windows 7.

A bit of further googling into the issue told me, grub2 refuses to detect non-UEFI bootloaders, which contradicts with my previous experiences (the same operating system has been installed before and dual-boot worked as it should).

A few more details:

- The two operating systems are installed on to separate SDDs, each with its own bootloader.
- The BIOS supports both boot methods (Legacy/UEFI)
- For the Windows 7 disk, `fdisk -l` says `Disklabel type: dos`, which I assume implies, this SDD still uses the old MBR/Legacy boot method.
- I can still tell the BIOS to boot the Windows disk and it works. This excludes the possibility of a broken Windows bootloader being the cause for grub not to detect it.
- Ubuntu 18 uses grub2 (the default) as a bootloader. Since I already installed a new system, I can't tell which boot-type the old system used, or which Disklabel type it had.
- When running `update-grub2` only Ubuntu gets detected.
- Running `os-prober` yields no result (respectively, an empty one).
- I can mount and access the Windows disk when running Ubuntu.

One solution I found was to change the Windows boot type to UEFI, which I don't want to do, since this would imply migrating Windows or reinstalling it, which I don't want to do.

Does anyone know, how to install Ubuntu in a non-UEFI way, or make grub2 detect the MBR based Windows installation? I don't prefer any of the two (or possible other) ways.

If you need any further information, I'm very happy to deliver them.

Best wishes and thank you already for your answers!

Comment: can you confirm that you can still boot into your Windows installation if you select that drive as primary in BIOS?

Comment: Yes, this works. Technically, I could use the BIOS to do the selection between Windows and Ubuntu, but I was hoping to use grub for this job, since it's way more comfortable that way.

Comment: if you want to install Ubuntu as UEFI, it is correct that you must have a separate ESP (EFI System Partition) at `/boot/efi` This is different from the MBR boot partition.  You can install Ubuntu *not* in EFI mode by selecting the non-EFI option in BIOS for the flash drive.  Since you already have a non-EFI OS (Windows), it would probably be easier to go this route.  FYI it is incorrect that GRUB does not detect or work with MBR.

Comment: The BIOS doesn't provide me with such an option. It even explicitely states `UEFI: USB ...`, but no regular `USB: ...`.
I will try to figure out why this is and/or how to create a non-uefi bootable device.

Comment: you may need to go further into the BIOS settings and disable UEFI altogether.  Or see if there is a setting that disables/enables UEFI from flash drives etc.

Comment: Thank you Nmath! As you said, the trick was to get the installation device to boot in legacy mode. When doing so, Ubuntu installs regularly, doesn't complain about any uefi /target/ things and also grub detects Windows now properly.
If you summarize your comments in an answer, I can/will mark it as correct. (Can't do so for comments.)

Comment: Also be sure to have grub in MBR of Ubuntu drive and Windows boot loader in MBR of Windows drive. Grub often wants to default to first drive and often Windows is first drive. You can do that during install using Something Else or reinstall grub to correct drive manually after install and reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR of Windows drive. Often easier with Boot-Repair and one of the few Windows fixes Boot-Repair can do. But best to also have Windows repair disk or installer with repair console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every motherboard has a slightly different BIOS/UEFI interface but you should notice two (or more) different entries for your USB drive in your boot options or boot priority list.  Make sure that the non-UEFI option is chosen so the installer will default to legacy mode.

Otherwise, if you select your flash drive preceded with `UEFI:`, the installer will default to UEFI.

If there aren't any non-UEFI options shown, you may need to search for additional settings in your BIOS to disable UEFI or enable MBR.  Sometimes this is called "legacy mode".  Refer to your manufacturer's manual for hardware specific questions on how to do this.

Booting into legacy mode with the USB should make it easier for GRUB and the installer to find your Windows installation.