# EFI partition not found error during Ubuntu installation

Tags: 18.04

[After executing sudo parted -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0LXz.png)

[partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXl4F.png)

[problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XSMv.png)

Can anyone help me solve this issue :(

I created all the partitions, still it is showing the error.
PS: I even tried mounting the sda7 as EFI partition and the same thing shows.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105083/discussion-on-question-by-vicky-dirtyd-efi-partition-not-found-error-during-ubun).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue in EFI mode installation, you could do:

- Shrink your `sda7` releasing 500Mb of disk space
- Create new partition using released space in FAT32
- Make your newly created FAT32 partition bootable:
  **Garted** -> **Right click on FAT32 partition** -> **Manage Flags** -> Check **Boot** and **ESP**

But it is better to install Ubuntu in BIOS mode by disabling EFI option for booting from USB stick. Because of Ubuntu installation in EFI mode will not detect your windows MBR partition. Maybe there's a way to make grub boot windows, but most probably a lot of investigation could be required to do it.

If you want to convert your windows to EFI mode, you need to reinstall it, but it will require your data backup.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147473/combining-uefi-ubuntu-with-mbr-windows)

Comment: Best not to create ESP as you have Windows on a MBR(msdos) partitioned drive which means it is installed in the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Your hardware must be newer & UEFI. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, but users can install in BIOS mode.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, you're right!